# Help identifying a bag containing many white plates

Tags: set-identification

I have a bag with number 135149. Can anyone help identify the set it comes from?

[image: bag photo]

Answer (score 5):

This bag is from [75053-1: The Ghost](https://brickset.com/sets/75053-1/The-Ghost)

[image]